# Swift 4.3 - protocols passing data between 2 files

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I am struggling with understanding how protocols work. I have 2 files and want to use protocol to pass data... Here's what I am doing:

In ViewController.swift

```
protocol workingProtocol { func myFunc(strValue: String)}    

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var interactor = workingProtocol
  @objc func doneBtn() {
     interactor.myFunc(strValue: "str")
  }
}
```

In Interactor.swift

```
class Interactor {
 func myFunc(strValue: String) {
   print(strValue)
 }
}
```

The data is not printing from Interactor.swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't see how you inject interaction class, also your code has some problem with syntax. Here is how it should look:

```swift
protocol WorkingProtocol: AnyObject {
 func myFunc(strValue: String)
}    

final class ViewController: UIViewController {

  var interactor: WorkingProtocol

  @objc func doneBtn() {
     interactor.myFunc(strValue: "str")
  }
}

final class Interactor: WorkingProtocol {

 func myFunc(strValue: String) {
   print(strValue)
 }
}
```

And how to use:

```swift
let interactor: WorkingProtocol = Interactor()
let vc = ViewController(interactor: interactor)

vc.doneBtn()
```

Comment: Where do I add this lines? let interactor: WorkingProtocol = Interactor()

Comment: where you initialize your ViewController. You should inject **interactor** into your ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Protocols defines a **blueprint** of methods, properties and other requirements that suite a piece of functionality.

This is an example about how it works based on your code

```
protocol ProtocolName {
 func functionName(strValue: String)
}

class ViewController {
  var interactor: ProtocolName? = nil

  @objc
  fileprivate func doneBtn() {
    interactor?.functionName(strValue: "Passing data to interactor using protocols")
  }
}

class Interactor: ProtocolName {
  func functionName(strValue: String) {
    print("Showing value\n", strValue)
  }
}

let interactor = Interactor()
let viewController = ViewController()
viewController.interactor = interactor
viewController.doneBtn()
```

Another example:

```
protocol ProtocolName {
 func functionName(strValue: String)
}

class ViewController1 {
  let interactor = Interactor1()

  /// Init or viewDidLoad() if you're using ViewController classes.
  init() {
    interactor.delegate = self
  }
}

extension ViewController1: ProtocolName {
  func functionName(strValue: String) {
    print("Printing the value: \(strValue)")
  }
}

class Interactor1 {
  var delegate: ProtocolName?

  func someAction() {
    delegate?.functionName(strValue: "Executed action in interactor.")
  }
}

let vc = ViewController1()
vc.interactor.someAction()
```